# Why cannot I not do the string formatting at the start of a variable python

Tags: python

Why does this work:

```
with open(filename+'%s' % i, "w")
```

But this doesn't:

```
with open('%s'+filename % i, "w")
```

I want to add the number of i to the start of the filename each time it loops through. But adding it at the end adds the number to the extension example - filname.xml0

Comment: The multiplicative operators `*`, `/`, `//` & `%` have higher precedence than the additive operators `+` & `-`. The `%` is still essentially the modulus operator, even though it does a different job when you use it for string interpolation, so it still has it's usual precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator has a [higher operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the `+` operator, and it is applied *first*.

Python executes:

```
filename + ('%s' % i)
```

in the first case, and

```
'%s' + (filename % i)
```

in the second.

You could add parentheses to override this:

```
('%s' + filename) % i
```

Or you could interpolate both `filename` and `i` into a template:

```
'%s%s' % (i, filename)
```

This has the added advantage that any `%` characters *in the filename* are not seen as special (which would cause problems).

If you are using Python 3.6 or newer, you should really use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to do the same work; these expressions are way faster:

```
with open(f'{i}{filename}', 'w') as fileobj:
```

Note the `f` prefix to the string, the `{}` slots are filled with the results of the expressions contained within them. This is also clearer and more readable, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Operator priority means the `%` has higher precedence than the `+`.

So

```
with open('%s'+filename % i, "w")
```

is equivalent to:

```
with open('%s' + (filename % i), "w")
```

You could parenthesise:

```
with open(('%s'+filename) % i, "w")
```

but that will go horribly wrong if the filename contains a literal `%` character.

So use string formatting for both:

```
with open('%s%s' % (filename, i), "w")
```

or

```
with open('{}{}'.format(filename, i), "w")
```

or just concatenate strings:

```
with open(str(i) + filename, "w")
```

Answer (score 0):

The operations priority is the problem Simply add brackets like so:

```
with open(('%s'+filename) % i, "w")
```

Otherwise you are first trying to format `filename` using `i` and only after that add the result to `%s`.